# $x^2 - y^2=9$, $2y-x=3$, Find maximum value of $\dfrac{y}{x}$

Tags: maxima-minima

I came across this question and have no idea what to do. Given,
$$
x^2-y^2=9 \\
2y-x=3
$$

find maximum value of $\dfrac{y}{x}$

Comment: You have to find the maximum value of $y/x$ where $x,y$ satisfy the two equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $x = 2y - 3$, we have:

$$(2y-3)^{2} - y^{2} = 9$$

$$4y^{2} - 12y + 9 - y^{2} = 9$$

$$3y^{2} - 12y = 0$$

$$3y(y - 4) = 0$$

$$y = 0, 4$$

$$(x, y) = (-3, 0), (5, 4)$$

$$\frac{y}{x} = 0, \frac{4}{5}$$

$$\boxed{\max(\frac{y}{x}) = \frac{4}{5}}$$

Comment: yh I solved the simultaneous equations but only got 1 solution (5,4) so i was confused by the max forgot about the y=0 solution

Answer (score 1):

Solve the system of equations, for instance, with $2y-x=3\iff x=2y-3$; insert this value in the first equation to obtain $(2y-3)^2-y^2=9\iff ...\iff y\cdot(y-4)=0$. Thus the solutions $(x,y)$ are $(3, 0)$ and $(5, 4)$. Which one of them yields the maximum ratio $\frac yx$?

Comment: I believe the first equation yields "$x = 2y \textbf{ - } 3"$

Comment: You're right @JoshuaWang! Thanks for outlining the typo